# Elegant way for instantiating one of a collection of objects based on a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have a JSON string representing an `alert` that is passed to my controller... and one of the parameters in the JSON string is which kind of an `alert` it is.   I.E. a panic `alert`,  an instrument `alert`, a hard drive `alert` etc.

I have objects for each of my `alert` types extending a base `alert` class.

```
class base_alert
    ...
end

class panic_alert < base_alert
    ...
end

class hard_drive_alert < base_alert
    ...
end

class instrument_alert < base_alert
    ...
end
```

Is there an elegant way to conditionally instantiate an object based on the paramater passed into the json string?

I.e. if the json parameter is for a panic alert the controller will recieve this and instantiate the panic `alert` class.

I really don't want a huge `if` or `switch` statement.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have objects for each of my `alert` types extending a base `alert` class"? Your question should include the relevant code that you've written so far.

Comment: does the name of the json alert string match the class name?

Comment: I added some code for clarity.  I hope it's clearer.  If there's anything else I can add to help it be more understandable, please let me know.

Comment: @Nabeel,   no unfortunately.  It's actually a number indicating the alert type. However, If there's an elegant way to do it if the class names are the same I can put it through an object literal first to give it the same class name.

Comment: use a case statement then, probably the easiest way

Comment: If the json alert string did match the class name what would you suggest?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.const_get("class_name")` to get the class. If they are not similar you could either make them similar or create a hash constant to map them

i.e.:

```
MAP = { 'alert_1' => 'hard_drive' }

Object.const_get(MAP['alert_1']).new
=> #<SomeClass:0x00000001fb2538>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adverse to a switch statement (which may be considered the most ideal) and your alerts are being passed up as a number, you store an ALERTS constant and use some metaprogramming to instantiate the proper alert:

```
# For example given an alert value a
ALERTS = {
  1 => "panic",
  2 => "hard_drive",
  3 => "instrument"
}

alert = eval("#{ALERTS[a]}_alert.new")
```